# Extension-injected <script> tag execution order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a browser extension that does the following:

1. Executes a content script at `document_start`.
2. This content script inserts a `<script>` element with a `src` attribute of a JavaScript file in my extension.
3. This JavaScript file hooks some browser functions.

All three of these things need to happen before any script runs on the loaded page.  To that end, I've created the following in my `manifest.json`:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://example.com/*",
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["js/inject.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Then for `inject.js`:

```
console.log('Inject');
const scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
scriptEl.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('js/hooks.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptEl);
```

In `hooks.js`, for now, just some debugging:

```
console.log('Hooks');
```

Finally, on my test HTML page, I have some script as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async (e) => {
        console.log('DOMContentLoaded');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting to see the following on the console, in this order:

```
Inject
Hooks
DOMContentLoaded
```

Instead, what I see:

```
Inject
DOMContentLoaded
Hooks
```

If I inspect the DOM with my browser's developer tools, I see that the `<script src=".../js/hooks.js"></script>` is inserted immediately before `<head>`.  This is expected by the injection method.

Is there a way to get this script to execute before all other scripts?

Comment: Random idea, what happens if you switch `scriptEl.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('js/hooks.js');` with ``scriptEl.src = `data:text/javascript;base64,Y29uc29sZS5sb2coJ2hlbGxvIHdvcmxkJyk7`;``?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `Inject`, `DOMContentLoaded`, `hello world`.

Comment: Ah, too bad, I was hoping the `getURL` call or src retrieval had something asynchronous, sounds like something else's going on. I remember that Tampermonkey used (uses?) a synchronous XMLHttpRequest for a similar issue, not sure if it's the same as the one you're describing here

Comment: @CertainPerformance Wow, that sounds nasty.  :-)  But, probably one way to fix it.  My old way was to inject the text of a function in between some script tags, but this started to get really complicated when I expanded that to include modules with bundlers.  Sync XHR... might work for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the idea from @CertainPerformance, here is a hackaround solution:

```
console.log('Inject');

const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', chrome.runtime.getURL('js/hooks.js'), false);
req.send(null);
if (req.status === 200) {
  const scriptEl = document.createElement('script');
  scriptEl.textContent = req.responseText;
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(scriptEl);
}
```

Nasty stuff, but gets the job done for today.  If anyone has a more appropriate solution, let me know!

Comment: This is a known bug/peculiarity in Chrome, see https://crbug.com/634381 and [Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879), also try using a compiler/bundler that inserts your js file contents as a literal string into the compiled content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the tips and the link.  Yeah, I was messing with my bundler but don't have a good way to get it working right now.  Will probably switch bundlers later.  This info gets me running for now, thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with Manifest V3...